# Adding HTML class attributes to Entity Reference field links in View

Tags: 8, views, nodes

I have a view ("Tasks") that pulls in Task nodes, complete with sorting and filtering. Each Task can have multiple nodes attached via the "Related Articles" field (`field_related_articles`). I am trying to loop through each node (which can be a Video, Document, Article, etc.) and assign each link a class name depending on the type.

For example, a "Document" node attached to a Task would display a hyperlink with the `document` class. Video nodes will be `video`, and so on.

Here is my preprocess that is targeting the specific field:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_field__node__field_related_articles(&$variables) {
  $items = $variables['items'];

  foreach ($items as $index => $item) {
    $content_type = $item['content']['#options']['entity']->type->entity->label();
    $class_name = slugify($content_type); // custom function

    $variables['items'][$index]['attributes']['class'] = [$class_name];
  }

}
```

When I inspect the `$variables` array, I see the following, which looks okay to me (but I can't be sure):

[image: The items array inside $variables]

As you can see, the `attributes` object now has a `class` value for each `items` value (I have two). However, in the HTML, the classes do not show up:

[image: HTML output]

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the twig template? It looks like you've rendered the top level attributes twice instead of the item attributes.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured out the problem.

I wasn't supposed to touch the `$variables['items'][…]['attributes']` *object*, I was supposed to **create** a `$variables['items'][…]['content']['#attributes']` *array* instead and put the class name(s) there.

Having done so, that now works.